# Convolution in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, convolution

I want to take convolution in opencv with cpp  my code gives the error that is below

**error C2040: 'H' : 'int [1][2]' differs in levels of indirection from 'cv::Mat'**

I want to take conv between H= [1,-1] and image   ||  V=[1;-1] and image

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void main(){

    Mat image =imread("C:\\Users\\merve\\Desktop\\images3.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    int h,w;



    Size s=image.size();
    h = s.height;
    w = s.width;

    int i,j;
    Mat H_gradient;
    
    int H [1][2] = {1,-1};
    int V [2][1] = {{1},{-1}};


    filter2D( image, H_gradient, -1 , H, Point( -1, -1 ), 0, BORDER_DEFAULT );

    namedWindow( "filter2D Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "filter2D Demo", H_gradient );

        
    

    
    waitKey(0);





}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you would like to compute horizontal gradient, right? So instead of using two dimensional array of ints as a kernel, use cv::Mat object (from [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=filter2d#filter2d): *a single-channel floating point matrix*) :

```
cv::Mat kernelH(1, 3, CV_32F);
kernelH.at<float>(0,0) = 1.0f;
kernelH.at<float>(0,1) = 0.0f;
kernelH.at<float>(0,2) = -1.0f;
```

and the use it instead H variable in your code. Similar, to compute vertical gradient, try  following snippet:

```
cv::Mat kernelH(3, 1, CV_32F);
kernelH.at<float>(0,0) = 1.0f;
kernelH.at<float>(1,0) = 0.0f;
kernelH.at<float>(2,0) = -1.0f;
```

Also, remember about converting color image to grayscale before applying filter2d.

Comment: Thanks for reply... Yes I am trying to do vertical and horizontal gradient. Must the kernelH =[1 0 -1] ? because my source shows the kernelH=[1 -1] or is there more than one kernel for taking gradient?